# How to validate HMAC the shopify webhook - nodejs Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, shopify, shopify-api-node

I cannot able to validate the webhook response from the shopify by using the "**crypto-js**" package.

i am using: "Node.js, AWS-Lambda , crypto-js" and the following code to validate

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
var getRawBody = require("raw-body");
var Buffer = require('buffer/').Buffer  // note: the trailing slash is important!
    
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
        let hmac = event.hmac;
       
        const bodyString = Buffer.from(event.body, "utf8").toString();
        var bodyForVerification = bodyString.replace('/\\/g', '\\\\');
    
        let firma = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(bodyForVerification, "****");
        var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(firma);
        let calculatedHmacBase = hashInBase64.toString(CryptoJS.enc.hex);
        if(hmac == calculatedHmacBase {
        console.log("verificado");    
    }
    };
```

The HMAC is different..

Answer (score 0):

I use this middleware for my public and private apps on Shopify,
using crypto, it is deprecated but works fine for my code.

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
const verify = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.query.shop) {
    if (!req.query.signature) {
      return false;
    }
    console.log(req.query);
    const signature = req.query.signature;
    const sharedSecret = process.env.SHOPIFY_SHARED_SECRET;
    const def = req.query;
    delete def.signature;
    const sortedQuery = Object.keys(def).map(key => `${key}=${Array(def[key]).join(',')}`).sort().join('');;
    const calculatedSignature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', sharedSecret).update(sortedQuery).digest('hex');
    if (calculatedSignature === signature) {
      console.log('validated');
      return next();
    }
    console.log('not validated');
    return false;
  }
};
module.exports = verify;
```

Comment: Hi, ¿How can i get the lib crypto?... I'm looking for it but didn't find it.. In npm is deprecated  and I can not download the module to be able to upload to the lambda

Comment: Just type npm i crytpo

Comment: in writing "npm install crypto". I download only two files - "package.json and "README".  inside the file it says "This package is no longer supported and has been deprecated. To avoid malicious use, npm is hanging on to the package name."..

Comment: It doesnt create any issue, please try running your code for any further issues

Comment: You don't have to install `crypto`.. it's a core Node package: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html